# CKEditor 4: How to add CSS stylesheet from plugin?

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

Tried this for now, but no luck

```
  editor.addCss(this.path + 'tabber.css');
  editor.document.appendStyleSheet(this.path + 'tabber.css');
```

Full code

```
(function () {
  CKEDITOR.plugins.add('tabber', {
    init: function (editor) {
      editor.ui.addButton('addTab', {
        command: 'addTab',
        icon: this.path + 'icons/tabber.png',
        label: Drupal.t('Insert tabs')
      });
      editor.addCss(this.path + 'tabber.css');
      editor.document.appendStyleSheet(this.path + 'tabber.css');
      editor.addCommand('addTab', {
        exec: function (editor) {
          editor.insertHtml('<dl>' +
            '<dt>Tab title 1</dt>' +
            '<dd><p>Tab content 1.</p></dd>' +
            '<dt>Tab title 2</dt>' +
            '<dd><p>Tab content 2.</p></dd>' +
            '</dl>');
        }
      });
    }
  });
})();
```

Solution (thanks for the answer for pointing the right way) inside init

```
  var cssPath = this.path + 'tabber.css';
  editor.on('instanceReady', function () {
    this.document.appendStyleSheet(cssPath);
  });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`CKEDITOR.addCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-addCss) accepts string as a parameter, so there's no way to pass any path there. [`CKEDITOR.document.appendStyleSheet`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.document-method-appendStyleSheet) is correct though ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YnmX/)):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    on: {
        instanceReady: function() {
            this.document.appendStyleSheet( 'http://path.to.your.css' );
        }
    }
} );
```

Just make sure that:

1. Your CSS exists.
2. It has correct permissions to be read.
3. Your HTML is [allowed in the editor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) (also read the [integration guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf) as since 4.1 you need to adjust `allowedContent` for your command).

I guess you may also find [CKEDITOR.getUrl](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-getUrl) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to **config.js**:

config.contentsCss = [CKEDITOR.getUrl( 'contents.css' ), '/path/to/your/css'];

This will append your CSS file to the default CKEditor styles. The advantage of this method over instanceReady is that (for me at least) when the user toggled modes from Source to Visual, the instanceReady event would not re-fire and custom styles would not be reapplied.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CKEditor 4.4 or later, you can use

`editor.addContentsCss( pluginDirectory + 'styles/example.css' );`

If you are using CKEditor an older version like 4.3, you should use:

```js
beforeInit: function(editor) {
        var ccss = CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss;
        if(typeof ccss == 'string'){
            ccss = [ccss];
        }
        ccss.push('/css/style.css');
        CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = ccss;
    }
```

Take a look at this ticket when the feature was created:
https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11532